XGBoostError: basic_string::_M_replace_aux
I've trained the Model on SageMaker ...and after unzip the model.tar.gz, I got the file xgboost-model without any extension.
I load the model with this code:
import xgboost
xgb_model_file = "**xgboost-model**"
xgb_model = xgboost.Booster()
xgb_model.load_model(xgb_model_file)

It's work 2 to 3 days, and then suddenly it's bugging now with this error message:
XGBoostError: basic_string::_M_replace_aux
